# Should my answer, which addresses implications in the framing of a question, have been deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, moderation, deletion

My answer to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56820/are-the-numbers-on-this-arab-jew-ethnic-cleansing-meme-accurate/56827) has been deleted, despite providing a skeptical discussion of the meme posted. It was respectfully written.

At time of deletion, the answer had 8 upvotes, and no comments indicating any issues with the answer.

The ostensible reason for deleting the answer is that it did not answer the question, despite the accepted answer going far beyond the question to assert “yes, the meme is accurate in its primary statements”. My answer was posted after raising my concern about that answer with the author, and my criticism being rejected. The comment raising this concern, and clarifications regarding it were also deleted. I felt the need to point out that the meme is not accurate in it’s primary statements, despite using facts.

A larger issue this raises, is that a questioner can post a misleading meme, ask a narrow question about a fact in the meme, and then be endorsed by skeptics.stackexchange without challenge.

In my answer I gave the example of a climate graph which could show a cooling globe despite using factual data. Would skeptics.stackexchange allow the posting of such a graph with the question ‘is the data accurate?, and delete answers that address the broader implications of the graph? If this site is providing a “fact check, true” stamp on misleading propaganda, I find that hugely problematic.

This site is called skeptics, not fact checks. Is applying skeptical analysis to questions is off topic?

If my answer to the question is not acceptable, then I think the question as a whole should be deleted, because otherwise it invites the posting of misleading arguments attached to narrow questions.

Edit to address OddThinking's answer:

**1. Implications of implications and meandering off topic**

In my opinion this can largely be addressed through the voting system and does not need to be the subject of moderator action. I reiterate - not one comment was made on my answer to suggest it needed improvement.

In particular, this question already had an accepted answer which had drawn a conclusion about the accuracy of the meme as a whole, rather than just the numbers. It 'opened the door' so to speak. The expansion of the topic is a fait-accompli, endorsed by the asker.

I did address the numbers, but since that aspect was already covered I can do what? Repeat information already given? That would be plagiarism, so I cited the existing answers.

The notion that each question exists in isolation, absent the context of the other answers, does not provide for answers which address the flaws of other answers.

**2. You can continue to downvote and post comments helpful to the author and voters on propaganda answers. You can continue to post full answers without the propaganda parts in competition.**

My comments doing the former were deleted, and I was not given any opportunity to improve my answer before deletion.

**3. If skeptical analysis means your own independent thoughts and opinions about a topic, then YES, THAT IS OFF-TOPIC.**

I reject the suggestion my answer was opinion based. It was an analysis of the logical structure of the argument made in the meme. I largely omitted my own opinion, though I did perhaps err in linking to 'The Ethnic Cleansing of Palestine' in my conclusion.

**4. The question, the comments, and the answers all received a huge number of flags - it required more mod attention than this silly meme deserved.**

That people decided to flag comments and answers, including constructive ones, is not my fault. People should be directed to use the voting system.

**It also largely avoided empirical data (except about climate change) although it did mention 1948's 750,000 Palestinian refugees.**

That being the most relevant empirical data to the question of whether ethnic cleansing has been committed against Palestinians.

**It didn't even reach a conclusion about ethnic cleansing, just saying "A case can be made".**

That, indeed, is the point. It's largely a matter of opinion whether the events in question meet the definition provided as it requires intent. But that a conclusion is not required in order to refute the logical structure of the meme.

I'll drop this now, but I urge the moderation team to rethink the policy what is on topic in relation to all answers. If the accuracy of the meme as a whole is on topic for the accepted answer, it should be on topic for all answers.

Screenshots of deleted post:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I note that my comments on the accepted answer have also been deleted, despite offering constructive criticism on the answer.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the text or a screen shot of the text for those who can't see deleted answers.

Comment: @Joe-W Thanks. I have added screenshots.